# javascript error with html textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I just added a textarea to my page which is an "include" to another page...I have some script that does a counter in the textarea...heres the code for that:

```
function characterCounter(spanId, maxLen, inputElement)
{
  if (spanId)
  {
      // Update the counter the user sees.
      var whatIsLeft = maxLen - inputElement.value.length;

      if ( whatIsLeft < 0 ) whatIsLeft = 0;
      spanId.innerText = whatIsLeft;
  }

  // Restrict user from entering more than the maxlen.
  if ( inputElement.value.length > maxLen )
  {
      inputElement.value = inputElement.value.substring( 0, maxLen );
  }
}
```

The I get a javascript error here as soon as I type....any suggestions

```
      <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="2" cols="125" 
                 onkeypress="characterCounter(commentsCounter,${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                 onkeydown="characterCounter(commentsCounter,${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                 onkeyup="characterCounter(commentsCounter,${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)">
      </textarea>

      <a href="javascript:addComment();"><img src="../images/icon_add.gif" border="0" alt="Add"/></a>
     </td>
        You have <strong><span id="commentsCounter">${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH'] - fn:length(commentForm.comment)}</span></strong> characters left.<br />
```

Thanx

these two lines say:  "object expected"...in the debugger

```
onkeydown="characterCounter(commentsCounter,250, this)"
                 onkeyup="characterCounter(commentsCounter,250, this)">
```

Comment: You should only bind the function to one of these events...

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
onkeydown="characterCounter(commentsCounter,250, this)"
onkeyup="characterCounter(commentsCounter,250, this)">
```

With

```
onkeydown="characterCounter('commentsCounter',250, this)"
onkeyup="characterCounter('commentsCounter',250, this)">
```

And

```
function characterCounter(spanId, maxLen, inputElement)
{
   if (spanId)
```

With

```
function characterCounter(id, maxLen, inputElement)
{
    spanId = document.getElementById(id);
   if (spanId)
```

Your code as it stands, expects commentsCounter to be a globally accessible variable. In order to access the element with id commentsCounter, you must use **document.getElementById**

Comment: only thing...that javascript function is used by alot of different things...so i cant change that function

Comment: Then just change it to `characterCounter(document.getElementById('commentsCounter'),250, this)`.

Comment: I added this:
                <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="2" cols="125" 
                     onkeypress="characterCounter(document.getElementById('commentsCounter'),${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                     onkeydown="characterCounter(document.getElementById('commentsCounter'),${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                     onkeyup="characterCounter(document.getElementById('commentsCounter'),${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)">
                  </textarea>

Comment: '
                <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="2" cols="125" 
                     onkeypress="characterCounter(document.getElementById('commentsCounter'),${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                     onkeydown="characterCounter(document.getElementById('commentsCounter'),${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                     onkeyup="characterCounter(document.getElementById('commentsCounter'),${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)">
                  </textarea>    '

Comment: I think the problem was accessing that javascript page where it was in its on page.  When i put the script at the top of the jsp and added the single quotes.  It worked

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks to be expecting a DOM node for `spanID` and you are passing it the id of `commentsCounter` without quotes.  You probably want this somewhere in a `<script>` tag after the `<span id='commentsCounter'>` has been loaded:

```
You have <strong><span id="commentsCounter">${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH'] - fn:length(commentForm.comment)}</span></strong> characters left.<br />

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var commentsCounter = document.getElementById("commentsCounter");
</script>
```

Then you don't need to modify the key event handlers for the textarea, as `commentsCounter` is now a proper, non-empty variable.

Comment: only thing...that javascript function is used by alot of different things...so i cant change that function

Comment: My example doesn't require you to change the function.  You only need to add the `<script>` tag after `<span id='commentsCounter'>` and your function will continue to work exactly as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

```
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="2" cols="125" 
  onkeypress="characterCounter(\"commentsCounter\",${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"   
  onkeydown="characterCounter(\"commentsCounter\",${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)" 
  onkeyup="characterCounter(\"commentsCounter\",${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)">
</textarea>
```

The parameter that is suppose to be of type string must always be quoted.  If there is quote inside quote then in java script you can use " (double quote) between ' (single quote) or vice versa, optionally use escape character if required like I used in above example.  You can simply replace \" with '

Thanks
Shailendra